# Is there a limit to how often or how many posts a user can comment on or edit in a given period of time?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I have not posted anything for a long time, but I really enjoy reading questions and answers, regardless of the topic.

I've noticed [TheLethalCarrot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/58193/thelethalcarrot) is extremely active, commenting on/editing (if I'm not mistaken) every single new post, either the question or answer. (All very helpful edits and comments I'm sure)

I'm just wondering, if there is a limit to how many posts a user can edit or comment on in a given period of time?

[image: Typos... typos everywhere!!]

Comment: I'd just like to point out it's not every single one and I don't make it a habit to perform an action on everything. It's just that when I'm at a PC I generally have the home page open so I see a lot of what goes on and am usually one of the first there so it's inevitable I'll do more than most.

Comment: As for the question I don't believe so... there's flag rate limiting, limiting on the amount of flags, closures, deletions and votes. Might be different for lower rep and anonymous users though.

Comment: There's limits to edits such as tag edits or minor edits which are bumping posts that have shifted down organically back up. There's also limits to how many in a row one should do, but given TLCs aims are to uphold a high level of quality, and educate users I see nothing negative with his practice and don't really understand the purpose of the question.

Comment: Regarding the edit that usually doesn't happen but recently some of the other more active users are away so it's pretty much just me around... If you have complaint over any particular edit I would be happy to listen to constructive feedback but as far as I can tell they've all been worthwhile... most on new posts.

Comment: And regarding the image description I'm not sure if that is aimed at me or the original posts... my spelling isn't always the best. But note if there are still typos you can suggest an edit yourself and once you get >2k rep even edit without it going to queue.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I'm just adding that image as proof that what I said in my question was true (or at least very accurate): _I've noticed TheLethalCarrot is extremely active, commenting on/editing (if I'm not mistaken) every single new post,_

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot and I never actually inspect your edits. They're all very helpful edits and comments I'm sure. It's the quantity I was curious about, not the quality

Comment: @InguShama Sure but when wondering about the quantity I think it's important to think about the quality too.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot as I've already said multiple times, I'm sure every edit is very helpful. It's better save drawn out discussions for chat. Comments are not the place for them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.

There isn't really. As long as all of the comments are helpful and not too chatty, and otherwise in keeping with the purpose of comments, we don't *want* to limit it. New helpful comments are *always* encouraged. Why would we want to limit how helpful a user can be?

As for editing, the system allows users with 2,000+ reputation to edit as often as they want. Users with less than this amount of reputation can submit suggested edits, and have up to 5 pending from that user at a time.

Site policy is also to have, roughly, no more than 5 of the 15 most recently active questions to have been edited by a single user, although exceptions are made for when e.g. the community is doing a mass cleanup.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a source for that site policy, because last I checked, there's no real consensus there.

Comment: @Edlothiad - There's no 'consensus', but the 5/15 rule is currently in the lead.

Comment: @valorum, it’s not policy is all I’m saying, and claiming it as such is spreading false information

Comment: @Edlothiad - That's *been* policy for as long as I can remember. I don't have the exact meta post on hand, but it's been the rule of thumb for years.

Comment: The last meta was [focused on tag edits](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9850/5184), but it's the same issue/policy.

Comment: It's not a policy, by any definition of the word's use on this site, this has been stated to me dozens of times. A rule of thumb is not a policy. As phantom points out, the difference is a mere 2 votes, with the top sitting at 7. I myself could swing the favour of the votes. It is ***not*** a policy.

Comment: Discussions of how many edits are appropriate tend to tacitly assume that the edits are being made to *old* posts.  But this is not necessarily the case.  I sometimes, when I have time to kill, make a substantial number of (usually minor) corrections to posts that are already at the top of the front page.  The edits therefore do not materially affect what posts are most visible.

Comment: @Buzz Whilst the "edit policy" isn't concrete, large edit sprees are discouraged, especially when, as you say, the edits are minor. The policy is also top 15 posts and not the whole of the front page.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Ok, so seems as if there's no real site policy in place, and as long as I have enough rep and spare time, I can comment on and edit absolutely every single post? I guess that answers that.

Comment: @InguShama In short yes though there are soft policies in place that the mods enforce occasionally.

Comment: @InguShama if you go and try to edit every single post, you will be warned by myself, a few others and the mods. This site likes our front page, and we like to keep it neat. If you go comment on every post, no one will say anything, unless they're blatantly rude.

Comment: @Edlothiad I really wouldn't be bothered actually doing it. I just appreciate that's it's hypothetically possible.

Comment: @InguShama - That's it in a nutshell. Most users don't have the time or inclination to edit and comment on more than a fraction of posts.

Comment: There is explicit rate limiting on some (most?) actions for low reputation users on larger sites like Stack Overflow. I don't know if those same restrictions are in place on (much) smaller sites like this one, though. I don't think they are, but do you have a definite source that states they're not?